# Craft version number in database?

Tags: database

My provider upgraded to PHP7 and deleted all files outside of the public folder, where I had the system files (...). Is it possible to find out from the database which version (of Craft 2) I need to restore the website?

Comment: Yikes... find a new provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've already found it:

```
`craft_info` (`id`, `**version**`, `schemaVersion`, `edition`, `siteName`, `siteUrl`, `timezone`, `on`, `maintenance`, `dateCreated`, `dateUpdated`, `uid)
```

I can download the correct version from this great service: https://craftcms.com/support/download-previous-versions